# Having multiple SQL programs in my Maven program

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I have the code above, but only whichever on top seemed to work when I run my program as I'm getting an error "no driver found".

```
if (isMySQL) {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sportsdb?useSSL=false";
} else {
    url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=sportsdb";
}
```

Comment: You need to include more of your connection code (e.g. The Class.forName call, the line where you're getting the exception, etc.)